# Find index of a tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples and I want to find the index of a tuple if the tuple contains a variable. Here is a simple code of what I have so far:

```
items = [('show_scllo1', '100'), ('show_scllo2', '200')]
s = 'show_scllo1'
indx = items.index([tupl for tupl in items if tupl[0] == s])
print(indx)
```

However I am getting the error:

```
indx = items.index([tupl for tupl in items if tupl[0] == s])
ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you want the value, so you're asking for the index.

You can search the list for the next matching value, using [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> items = [('show_scllo1', '100'), ('show_scllo2', '200')]

>>> next(number for (name, number) in items
...      if name == 'show_scllo1')
'100'
```

So you don't really need the index at all.

Answer (score 5):

The following will return you the indices of the tuples whose first item is `s`

```
indices = [i for i, tupl in enumerate(items) if tupl[0] == s]
```

Comment: Hey guys I may be did not explain it clearly. I know that the tuples in the list of tuples are unique (they don't repeat). That's why I only need the index of that tuple because I am going to make some manipulations to it i.e indx = indx + 1. But now indx is a list instead of a simple integer number. So, I just need the index not a list of indices.

Comment: @user3578925 I'm surprised you are unable to figure how to go from a list of indices to the single index you want ...

Comment: You get a `list` because we assumed you were expecting potentially more than one match. If you know there will only be one match, no comprehension was necessary.

Comment: @donkopotamus I understand that these things may be obvious to you but they aren't to me as I am very unfamiliar with python, especially when it boils down to lists, tuples and lists comprehension. So far, I have only dealt with Fortran :-) So could you guys tell me how do I get the index without a list comprehension?

Comment: May be I should clarify further. I only know that the first element in the tuple and the second element could be anything. Therefore, I am trying to find the index of the tuple which has its first element "show_scllo1".

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am still waiting to find out if you guys know the answer to my question. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for the presence of a `list` in `items`, which doesn't contain a `list`. Instead, you should create a `list` of each index where the item of interest is found:

```
indx = [items.index(tupl) for tupl in items if tupl[0] == s]
```

Comment: bah you can do better than that T.H. (+1 all the same for showing OP the error of their ways)

Comment: `enumerate()` is (very) probably the one the OP wants, but technically these solutions could produce different behavior (for `list`s with duplicate elements), so I went with explaining the issue in a way that didn't affect the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
index = next((i for i,v in enumerate(my_tuple_of_tuple) if v[0] == s),-1)
```

Is how you should probably do that

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, your suggestion works but it returns the index in brackets i.e, [0]. How do I get just the number?

Comment: @user3578925 - It is in brackets because it is a `list` of all the matching indices. It just so happens to contain one match this time.